# Tuples within OrderedDict

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

I have the following OrderedDict

```
activities = OrderedDict([('eating',(1,False)),('drinking',(2,True)),('breathing',(3,True)),('talking',(4,False)),('walking',(5,False))])
```

I want to be able to able to run a function to reverse the True/False part of a particular entry.

so far I have the following:

```
def updateactivity(activity):
    activities = OrderedDict([(k, (1,False)) if k == activity else (k, v) for k, v in activities.items()])
```

Which does well to switch the value to False.
Is there a more elegant way to simply reverse the True/False in either direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpack each item's value into two variables/names then reconstruct with `not`.

```
d = collections.OrderedDict()
for k, (a,b) in activities.items():
    d[k] = (a, not b)
```

or

```
collections.OrderedDict((k,(a, not b)) for k, (a,b) in activities.items())
```

Comment: `d[k] = (d[k][0], not d[k][1])`

Comment: @IanAuld, I don't understand your comment. Are you suggesting I add that to my answer as an alternative solution?

Comment: No, OP had asked in a now deleted comment on this on how to only do it it to one entry as opposed to all of them. I was addressing that. Don't know why they deleted the comment though.